# Popup menu in VB.Net, equivalent to VB6?

Tags: vb.net, menu, vb6

In VB6 I am using Menu Editor to store a list of students.
e.g.
Students 
....Bob
....Joe
....Bill
....James

```
PopupMenu Students
```

I then used the Visual studio 2008 wizard to convert the Vb6 project to .NET.

How can I get this menu to work in .Net without too much change(event if the solution involves importing a VB6 DLL to .Net)?

In .Net Student is now :

```
Public WithEvents Students As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
```

So I did:

```
Students.ShowDropDown()
```

instead of:

```
PopupMenu Students
```

And it all works except the location. .net seems to be forcing the location to be 0,0. And I would like the menu to popup at the mouse click as it would in VB6.

VB.NET Code:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> Partial Class StudentForm

    Public WithEvents Students As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
    Public WithEvents John As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
    Public WithEvents MainMenu1 As System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
    Friend WithEvents ContextMenuStrip1 As ContextMenuStrip

    //Initialise Component
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.ContextMenuStrip1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(Me.components)
        Me.ContextMenuStrip1.Name = "ContextMenuStrip1"
        Me.ContextMenuStrip1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
        Me.Students = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
        Me.John = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
        Me.MainMenu1 = New System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
        Me.MainMenu1.SuspendLayout()

        Me.Students.Name = "Students"

        Me.Students.Text = "Students"

        Me.Students.Visible = False

        Me.Students.Checked = False

        Me.Students.Enabled = True


        Me.John.Name = "John"

        Me.John.Text = "Johnny"

        Me.John.Checked = False

        Me.John.Enabled = True

        Me.John.Visible = True

        MainMenu1.Items.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem(){ Me.Students})
        Students.DropDownItems.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem(){ Me.John})
        Me.MainMenu1.ResumeLayout(False)
    End Sub
End Class

'MouseUp Event - 
Students.ShowDropDown()' This work well bot the location is 0,0- not sure how to change

' I Also Tried Adding the context menu
ContextMenu1.Items.Add(Students)- ' This does not show with sudents. But it shows if I do `ContextMenu1.Items.Add("Test")`
ContextMenu1.Show()
```

Comment: You probably want a [ContextMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip). A `ToolStripMenuItem` is a child of a ContextMenuStrip. You can add an existing ToolStripMenuItem with `[ContextMenuStrip].Items.Add([ToolStripMenuItem])`. Controls have a ContexxtMenuStrip property that can be set (in the Form's Designer or at run-time) to an existing ContextMenuStrip object. You could also edit the Form's `Designer.vb` file (adding a ContextMenuStrip component to the Form beforehand).

Comment: @Jimi I realize that the project converted the PopMenu to a `MenuStrip`, but I have created a Context menu on the form, as you suggested and in the Form Load I tried Me.ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(Students) and nothing shows but when I also tried `Me.ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Test")` I Could see the menu with test. I stepped through the code And I notice all the students were in `Students` but nothing showed with Me.ContextMenuStrip1.Show()

Comment: If `Students` is actually a `ToolStripMenuItem` with child `ToolStripMenuItems` added in the Form's Designer code, then adding it to a ContextMenuStrip at run-time **will** show the Menu and sub-menu. Of course `Students`cannot be a MenuStrip (Option Strict Off may let you *try* to add it anyway). A ContextMenu is shown when you right-click on a Control when the `[Control].ContextMenuStrip` has been set to an existing ContextMenuStrip created at design-time or run-time.

Comment: The `Show()` method allows to show the CMS using absolute or relative position; e.g., to shown it at the left/top corner of a Control: absolute (screen coordinates): `contextMenuStrip1.Show([Control].PointToScreen(Point.Empty))`; relative coordinates: `contextMenuStrip1.Show([Control], Point.Empty)` etc. You should post your code, it's easier to debug code than thin air.

Comment: @Jimi I have added all the related code only the data(John-There is more in the collection) is minimal.

Comment: Is `ContextMenu1` actually a `ContextMenuStrip` class? If it is then it will work. I've described in the previous comments how to use a `ContextMenuStrip`, both assigned to Controls and with its `.Show([Arguments])` method. I don't know what `MouseUp Event` is referred to, since you shouldn't need any `MouseUp` event to show a ContextMenuStrip. That method was used the past millennium, with different type of Controls.